# to have a "good in" with somebody

Tags: meaning, slang, colloquialisms

In an article by Juan Cole about the recent release of the Kennedy-Files it states that

> According to an informant, Ruby had a “good in” with the Dallas police [...]

I haven't found anything like this phrasing in a quick google-search or anywhere on this forum. I get from the context, that having a "good in" reflects having good relations to somebody, but is this some form of outdated chicago colloquialism or what? Why doesn't google know it?

Comment: I voted to close this question, because *in* is a noun here (*good* is an adjective describing *in*) and the first two online dictionaries I looked at (Oxford and Cambridge)  contain this noun usage of *in*.

Comment: Then maybe I'm doing something wrong? I can't find it in either of these. I find "to have a good innings", but not "have a good in". Do you mean it's the singular of "goods" or something?

Comment: The reference would be clearer if it mentioned << a good 'in' >> rather than << a 'good in' >> (though the collocation is reasonably common).

Comment: You need to look up the word ***IN*** and scroll down and look for its NOUN usage (not preposition or adverb or adjective)  and you'll find the definition of **in** as a noun.

Comment: OMG got it, thanks big time! I've learned something today. Can be closed.

Comment: @Clare I think that's worth an answer--as much for the process of analyzing the phrase, concluding that "in" is a noun, thus being able to look it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An "in" with other people implies they a good relationship, are a known quantity. The writer saying "good in" though being redundant but may not expect others to know just what an "in" in quotes refers to.

It is indeed the noun and as slang does it gets passed to those who know what it means, to what degree or, in Ruby's case, if at all.